# How can I make a button redirect to my another page?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have been trying something like this

```
<form action="formularz.html"><button class="repair__button" type="button">Formularz serwisowy</button></form>
```

but it doesn't work, nothing happend when I clicked this button.
What am I doing wrong?

Of course "formularz.html" is on the same catalog as "index.html"

Comment: Use `<button class="repair__button" type="submit">Formularz serwisowy</button>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `type="button"`. It is for buttons that exist only to hang JavaScript from. You need a submit button (the default type) to submit a form.

---

You really should be using a link and not a form for this though. You can use CSS to make a link look like a button.

Answer (score 1):

Use `type="submit"` in Your Form To redirect The page :

Check Out This :

```
<form action="formularz.html"><button class="repair__button" type="submit">Formularz serwisowy</button></form>
```

Updated 2 :

As per your comment. form action will send the data to the next page. so if the page will not in the same directory or proper coding in formularz.html than it will not work... `<form action="">` will refresh the page. If You  dont want to refresh the page for sending the data Then Use AJAX. This might be helpful to you... Check The Working Code In snippest.

In First Button it will show the error because formularz.html page not found on the page and in second button i put the url of google. So when You Click on the submit button data will send to the google.

```html
  <form action="http://www.google.com" method="post">        
        <button type="submit" value="Submit Form" id="btnSubmitForm"> Submit The Form</button>
    </form>
```

**Important :**

Checkout This Code in Your Page.. In Snippest You Can't Because There is permission for that.

Answer (score 1):

Change normal button to submit button

Changed button style to look like a link

```css
.repair__button {
  background: none!important;
  border: none;
  padding: 0!important;
  font: inherit;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.repair__button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.repair__button:active,
.repair__button:hover {
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<form action="formularz.html">
  <button class="repair__button" type="submit">Formularz serwisowy</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's working for me. If you are using jQuery make sure, that you are not blocking any form submit using javascript, something like `$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {  
  event.preventDefault();
  //return false;
});`

Comment: "Changed button style to look like link as Quentin suggested" - That's the opposite to what I recommended.

Answer (score 0):

add a href to button

```html
<a href="formularz.html">
  <button class="repair__button" type="button">
    Formularz serwisowy
  </button>
</a>
```